# android customize list view prepends results

Tags: android, listview, prepend

I am using list view using "ArrayAdapter" to display number of items while user is looking at results when user click on load button i want results to load and prepends(add in the beginning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution

use adapter's insert method and add it to position 0 every time and also before adding reverse order so that first item will display at the beginning if don't reverse first item will display at end.